# Is it possible to user this code like the first one instead of second?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

```
def create_new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
        form.id_author = request.user.id
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'main/create_new.html')
```

```
def create_new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
             article = form.save(commit=False)
             article.author = request.user
            article.save()
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'main/create_new.html')
```

Is it possible to change the 2nd code into the first code??
it shows some kind of error

Comment: you can't alter the form before .is_valid() and you need to commit the form if you want to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at first you always need to check whether the form is valid or not, then after you can save the form with `commit=False` which creates a temporary instance, then you should assign any value in that instance.

The second approach is correct.